# MOD 1000000007 seems to be incorrect

Tags: c++, modulo

I have a simple question, How can I make this function return mod 1000000007 value? I am trying to achieve `((k+n)*n/k+n)%MOD` while avoiding intermediate overflow.

```cpp
long long func(long long n,int k){
    return ((k+n)*n)/k+n;
}
```

According to these 3 formulas:`(a+b)%c=((a%c)+(b%c))%c` and `(a-b)%c=((a%c)-(b%c))%c` and `(a*b)%c=((a%c)*(b%c))%c`, I wrote this:

```cpp
long long func(long long n,int k){
    return (((((((k%MOD)+(n%MOD))%MOD)*(n%MOD)))/k)%MOD+(n%MOD));
}
```

Which seems to be incorrect.

Comment: 1000000007 is more than 32 bits. This can potentially multiply two >32bit values, which requires more than 64 (or 63) bits to represent. Your multiplication is overflowing.

Comment: Use [GMP](https://gmplib.org/) or similar.

Comment: I don't understand why it shouldn't work according to commenters and answer. `1000000007` fits perfectly fine in 32 bits and is commonly chosen for programming tasks which require big number calculations. Since it fits in 32 bits, it's square will fit in 64 bits, and `long long` must be enough to hold it.

Comment: I've done this using ```cpp_int``` from boost library, but I wanted to use built-in data types like ```int``` and ```long long``` only.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen Well, can you tell me how can I implement that function correctly then?

Comment: Please clarify what you are trying to do. Are you trying to achieve  `((k+n)*n/k+n)  % MOD` while avoiding intermediate overflow?  If so then the method is not correct: (X/k) (mod M) is not the same as (X(mod M)/k)(mod M).  For example 16/2 (mod 10) is 8, but 16(mod 10)/2 is 3

Comment: Yes, I'm trying what you said exactly, how can I implement that correctly?

Comment: It's not so simple, see Chris Dodd's answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"division" in a modulo group is very different from normal division, so you can't just use `/` and `%` in C/C++; you need an algorithm to find the multiplicative inverse.  See https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/10552/division-modulo-a-prime-in-modular-arithmetic

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand. Why is it not ok to use `/` and `%` in the same expression?

Comment: because `/` does an integer divide not a modular divide.  To get an answer that works in the modular group, you need a modular divide.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen: Because the multiplicative inverse of 3 modulo 7 is 5 (multiplying 3 by 5 gives a number that is 1, modulo 7), but `3/5` produces zero, which is wrong. To calculate a multiplicative inverse of this sort, you need a different algorithm, such as the [Extended Euclidean Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm).